# Regular expression for email doesnt work in mvc cshtml

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, email-validation

i have a Regular expression like

```
 var filter = new RegExp(/^[+a-zA-Z0-9._-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9.-]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,4}$/i);
```

in `mvc`,but it shows an error after the @ in `cshtml` page which is obvious.
how can i rectify it so that it can work correctly.Thanks for any assistance.

P.S. Do provide if anyone have any other Regular expression.Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Escape `@` as `@@`, i.e. this should work:

```
var filter = new RegExp(/^[+a-zA-Z0-9._-]+@@[a-zA-Z0-9.-]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,4}$/i);
```

I like to use [Phil Haack's C# Razor Syntax Quick Reference](http://haacked.com/archive/2011/01/06/razor-syntax-quick-reference.aspx) as a, well... quick reference to Razor's syntax.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need regex in cshtml. you can use

```
<form>
    <input type="email" placeholder="me@example.com" required>
    <input type="submit">
</form>
```

Now this textbox is required with email format. You can use this same in mvc razor view engine also.

If you are delighted with my answer then mark as answer.